# Web layout issues only in Safari desktop

Tags: html, layout, safari, webkit, rendering

A client recently informed us that a store site I helped develop was displaying weirdly in Safari on desktop. I checked into his question and sure enough the client company's logo is getting cut off by the search bar:

[Safari desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKmd0.png)

I checked it against Chrome, Firefox and IE and all those seem to be displaying ok:

[Chrome view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkhGj.png)

I double checked element styling and it looks ok, I even got my developer involved, and even he is stumped - says Safari should be using Webkit and as such should display consistently.

[Link to the site](https://salemone.four51storefront.com/testing/catalog)

I've tried searching if others have had Safari-related rendering issues and haven't found any relevant articles.  Wondering if there needs to be browser-specific conditional formatting in my markup.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have a need for the third section, so remove that section and leave the container to be nested under the nav, it is the sixth nested element. Hopefully that should fix it :)

Comment: Joshua, thanks for checking it out - I'm just now getting back to working on this.  I commented out the extra section per your suggestion (in addition to spotting an error in my CSS as well as a class definition collision) and that seems to have worked.  Thanks!!